# Create categories in Looker Studio that intersect

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, visualization, data-modeling, looker-studio

I have a dataset in BiqQuery that represents orders and looks like:

| order_id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 883bcf7d | France |
| fb7e9b19 | Spain |
| 3jd2xjf11 | Sweden |

I want to create a Looker Studio report that shows how many orders there are in a few selected geographical `Areas`, where each area can intersect with each other. I would like to create a bar chart showing the total count of orders like:

```
Europe: 3
West Europe: 2
Alpine Region: 1
```

(where Europe, West Europe and Alpine Region is the X-axis)

I tried creating a calculated field for this using a CASE WHEN, but it doesn't work since I can only return one `Area` for my country dimension. So I tried for example:

```
CASE
    WHEN country = "Sweden" THEN "Europe"
    WHEN country = "France" THEN "Europe"
    WHEN country = "France" THEN "West Europe"
    ...
    ELSE "Unknown Area"
END
```

But this doesn't let me map one country to several areas.

I've also tried to return multiple values like:

```
CASE
    WHEN country = "Sweden" THEN "Europe"
    WHEN country = "France" THEN "Europe, West Europe, Alpine Region"
    ...
    ELSE "Unknown Area"
END
```

but with that the X-axis in my table is all the unique combinations of areas instead of just each area once.

How would one go about to solve this?

Comment: Can you share some data from table `Areas` ?

Comment: There is no table Areas, it's some categories that only certain viewers in Looker Studio are interested in, and therefore they don't exist as structured data in any table in BigQuery. I would like to do this kind of mapping (saying that Spain is part of West Europe AND Europe, etc.) directly in Looker Studio. Does this make sense or am I on the wrong path entirely?

Comment: How to know if a country is in Europe or not ? Can you edit your question and share what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Thnx! I updated the question with my CASE WHEN attempts. I've been trying to do this mapping (country to areas) directly in Looker Studio somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` clause to get a list of regions that are presented as comma-separated strings. Then, use `UNNEST` to turn those lists into rows, and apply `GROUP BY` :

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN country = 'Sweden' THEN 'Europe'
         WHEN country = 'France' THEN 'Europe, West Europe, Alpine Region'
         ....
         ELSE 'Unknown Area'
      END AS REGIONS
    FROM orders
)
SELECT REGION, COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM cte,
     UNNEST(SPLIT(REGIONS)) REGION
GROUP BY REGION
```